# Trouble extracting zip file in macOS

Tags: terminal, archive

I downloaded [Signal](https://signal.org/download/) desktop app from this URL:

- https://updates.signal.org/desktop/signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip

However, when attempting to extract the zip archive using `unzip` command, this is what I get:

```
~/Downloads$ unzip signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip 
Archive:  signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip or
        signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip.zip, and cannot find signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Should be pretty straightforward. I don't know what the problem is. `unzip -t` also fails with the same error.

I've tried to download this several times. Same problem. Also happens with `signal-desktop-mac-1.23.2.zip`. I doubt the archive is corrupted across several versions, and my system has no other known problems.

Comment: How about double clicking in Finder to extract? I just gave it a try and was able to extract the Signal.app bundle successfully.

Comment: Downloaded to my Downloads folder and double-clicked Signal app is the result.

Comment: I downloaded the link and when I went to the download folders the Signal.app was already extracted.

Answer (score 2):

Running

`file signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip`

in the Terminal outputs:

> signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip: Zip archive data, at least v?[0x314] to extract

indicating that there's some issue with how the zip file is encoded. That explains why `unzip` may have failed to extract the files from the compressed archive.

However, when attempting to extract via built-in Archive Utility by double clicking, or right clicking and selecting Open, the archive extracts successfully.

I tried it, successfully extracted Signal.app and was able to run it.

Comment: FWIW `file signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip` for me returns `signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract`; however, `unzip`, and or other installed third-party archiving utilities, except for the default macOS Archive Utility.app fail with the same/similar error message.

Comment: @user3439894 That's weird. Can you check the md5 checksum for the downloaded zip archive? Running `md5 signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip` on my system returns `MD5 (signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip) = 9556d48451cb93b909afb443bf456a44`.

Comment: `MD5(signal-desktop-mac-1.24.1.zip)= 9556d48451cb93b909afb443bf456a44` BTW This is on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: @user3439894 I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.4. Running `unzip -v` returns `UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.` and `Compiled with gcc 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14) for Unix Mac OS X on Feb 22 2019.`

Comment: For me, running `unzip -v` returns `UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP. Compiled with gcc 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31) for Unix Mac OS X on Oct  6 2017.` --- Regardless of the differences, the only thing in common so far that works is the macOS default Archive Utility.app.